# How can I get source code of nodejs from running app

Tags: node.js

I have accidentally delete source code of nodejs application, but this application is running, so how can I get source code back from running app?

I hope source code has been cached in some directory.

Comment: Should have used source control

Comment: It's in nodejs memory now.  Can't imagine how you would get it out of that memory from outside the process.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to recover the full file by attaching the debugger (as [TGrif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5156280/tgrif) suggested).

To actually recover the code:

1. Use `setBreakpoint('app.js', 10)`, where 10 is a line of the code you know will be ran over again in the running process
2. Say `pause`, then `next` until it's paused on the script you want to recover.
3. Finally, say `list(5000)`, where 5000 is an arbitrarily long number of lines to list.
4. You will now have your full script printed out, albeit with line numbers at the front, but you can use a [site like this](http://remove-line-numbers.ruurtjan.com/) to remove them.

Hope this helps anyone who encounters this unique issue in the future, as this took me a couple hours to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

There is maybe a way to retrieve some of your source code with the Nodejs debugger.

Assuming Linux OS, you need to get the process id of your application:

```
 $ ps -e | grep node
```

Next you entering your app in debug mode with something like that:

```
$ kill -s USR1 PID
```

where PID is the pid of your node app.

Then your start the debug console:

```
$ node debug -p PID
```

If you have an app console, you'll see:

```
Starting debugger agent.
Debugger listening on port 5858
```

In your debug console you should see a debug prompt and you can get available commands with:

```
debug> help
```

I am able to show some of the running app source with the *list* command:

```
debug> list(NUMBER_OF_LINE)
```

where NUMBER_OF_LINE is the number of source code line you want to display.

I'm not sure this is a *one shot try* for you or not because my source code was not deleted.
Hope you can get some results.

Comment: Would there be any way to protect the scripts from that? I mean, if I'm, importing encrypted scripts, the debugger shows the running/decrypted version, could that be avoided?