# Is there any way to recover the running node .js file?

Tags: node.js, recover

I was working on my node project and accidentally pasted some other code over my code, saved over, and closed the editor (can't undo).

The file is currently running in a powershell node process. Is there any way to extract out the code from it?

Windows "previous version" was not enabled, and I wasn't using git neither.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644035/how-can-i-get-source-code-of-nodejs-from-running-app) be of any service?